# Giving a data flag based on key word in the column cells

Tags: r

```
df <- 
 SUB    CONC    
  1     baseline (predose)
  2     screen 
  2     predose
```

I want to add a flag such that if CONC column has "predose" written in it regardless of other things in the cell, then give it a flag 1, otherwise 0.

```
   dfout <- 
 SUB    CONC                  PREDOSE  
  1     baseline (predose)     1 
  2     screen                 0
  2     predose                1
```

How can I do this in R? I used RStudio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a TRUE or FALSE column based on regexpr() findings in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269170/how-to-create-a-true-or-false-column-based-on-regexpr-findings-in-r) OR [Add column to data frame which returns 1 if string match a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698916/add-column-to-data-frame-which-returns-1-if-string-match-a-certain-pattern/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grepl` with `pattern` specified as 'predose' to create a logical vector and then coerce that to binary with `as.integer`

```
df$PREDOSE <- as.integer(grepl('predose', df$CONC))
df$PREDOSE
#[1] 1 0 1
```

Comment: yep! Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there a way, for example, to add flag number 2 if the cell has "screen", and 0 if it is not "predose" or "screen"? (i.e. incase if I need to put more than one flag)

Comment: @Amer In that case, you could create a key value dataset and merge with the original dataset